# One foreign key with multiple columns VS multiple foreign keys with single column

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the following two SQL code snippets:

SQL code 1:

```
 CONSTRAINT FK_E
      FOREIGN KEY (E1, E2, E3)
      REFERENCES F (E1, E2, E3),
```

SQL code 2:

```
 CONSTRAINT FK_E1
      FOREIGN KEY (E1)
      REFERENCES F (E1),

 CONSTRAINT FK_E2
      FOREIGN KEY (E2)
      REFERENCES F (E2),

 CONSTRAINT FK_E3
      FOREIGN KEY (E3)
      REFERENCES F (E3),
```

My question: are SQL code 1 and SQL code 2 equal? i.e. are they interpreted in a DBMS the same way? If not, what is the difference between them?

EDIT1: to be more specific consider the following ER diagram

[image]

Is the following SQL code correct?

```
 CREATE TABLE E
 (EID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);


 CREATE TABLE F
 (FID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);


 CREATE TABLE G
      (EID NUMBER,
      FID NUMBER,
      GNAME VARCHAR(50),
      CONSTRAINT G_PK
           PRIMARY KEY (EID, FID, GNAME),
      CONSTRAINT FK_G_EID
           FOREIGN KEY (EID)
           REFERENCES E (EID),
      CONSTRAINT FK_G_FID
           FOREIGN KEY (FID)
           REFERENCES F (FID)
 );


 CREATE TABLE R1
      (EIDE NUMBER,
      EIDG NUMBER,
      FIDG NUMBER,
      GNAME VARCHAR(50),
      ATTR1 NUMBER,
      CONSTRAINT PK_R1
           PRIMARY KEY (EIDG, FIDG, GNAME),
      CONSTRAINT FK_R1_EIDG_FIDG_GNAME
           FOREIGN KEY (EIDG, FIDG, GNAME)
           REFERENCES G (EID, FID, GNAME),
      CONSTRAINT FK_R1_EIDE
           FOREIGN KEY (EIDE)
           REFERENCES E (EID)
 );


 CREATE TABLE R2
      (FIDF NUMBER UNIQUE,
      FIDG NUMBER,
      EIDG NUMBER,
      GNAME VARCHAR(50),
      ATTR2 NUMBER,
      CONSTRAINT PK_R2
           PRIMARY KEY (EIDG, FIDG, GNAME),
      CONSTRAINT FK_R2_EIDG_FIDG_GNAME
           FOREIGN KEY (EIDG, FIDG, GNAME)
           REFERENCES G (EID, FID, GNAME),
      CONSTRAINT FK_R2_FIDF
           FOREIGN KEY (FIDF)
           REFERENCES F (FID)
 );
```

EDIT2: Are FK_R1_EIDE and FK_R2_FIDF redundant?

Comment: Not the same... Same row vs. different rows.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Simplify it to REFERENCES F (E1, E2) and consider valid fk's!

Comment: Typo alert: it's **foreign** (not "froeign" as you kept misspelling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: are SQL code 1 and SQL code 2 equal?

Not, they are not equivalent.

By [the definition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180)

> **Foreign Key Constraints**
>
> A foreign key constraint (also called a referential integrity
>   constraint) designates a column as the foreign key and establishes a
>   relationship between that foreign key and **a specified primary or
>   unique key, called the referenced key.** A composite foreign key
>   designates a combination of columns as the foreign key.

---

According to the above this declaration:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_E
      FOREIGN KEY (E1, E2, E3)
      REFERENCES F (E1, E2, E3),
```

assumes that there is either a primary key or unique constraint created on `F` table

```
CREATE TABLE F(
  .....
  .....
  CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY(E1, E2, E3)
)
```

---

while this declaration

```
 CONSTRAINT FK_E1
      FOREIGN KEY (E1)
      REFERENCES F (E1),

 CONSTRAINT FK_E2
      FOREIGN KEY (E2)
      REFERENCES F (E2),

 CONSTRAINT FK_E3
      FOREIGN KEY (E3)
      REFERENCES F (E3),
```

is in a need of existence of three constraints, either primary key or unique indexses/constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE F(
  .....
  .....
  CONSTRAINT my_pk1 PRIMARY KEY(E1),
  CONSTRAINT my_uq2 UNIQUE(E2),
  CONSTRAINT my_uq3 UNIQUE(E3)
)
```

---

Note 1- the table can only have one primary key, so only one constraint in your example could be the primary key, the rest 2 (or all 3) must be unique keys.

Note 2 - there is a slight semantic difference between the primary key constraint and the unique key constraint. The primary key values must be unique and **must not contain null values** while the unique key values can be NULL.

---

In the first case the table `F` can contain these values

```
E1  E2  E3
 1   1   1
 1   1   2
 2   2   1
```

and the child table can contain only these records:

```
E1  E2  E3
 1   1   1
 1   1   2
 2   2   1
```

but you cannot insert to the child table these combination of values because they don't exists in the parent table:

```
 E1  E2  E3
 1   2   1
 2   2   2
```

---

In the secondcase the table `F` can contain these values

```
E1  E2  E3
 1   1   1
 2   2   2
 3   3   3
```

but cannot contain these values, because each column must be unique:

```
E1  E2  E3
 1   1   1
 1   1   2
 2   1   3
```

while the child table **can** contain these records:

```
E1  E2  E3
 1   2   3
 3   1   2
 2   1   3
```